# Flattening of survey data using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I had to process this survey result in Tableau, then I thought the following pre-processing is best done using Python/Pandas combination.

Input:

```
  User      Day-1       Day-2   Day-3
    1       Good        Good    Bad
    2       Good        Ok      Ok
    3       Good        Ok      Ok
    4       Bad         Bad     Good
    5       Ok          Bad     Bad
```

Expected output:

```
User Question       Answer
1   Day-1           Good
1   Day-2           Good
1   Day-3           Good
2   Day-1           Bad
2   Day-2           Ok
2   Day-3           Good
3   Day-1           Ok
3   Day-2           Ok
3   Day-3           Bad
4   Day-1           Bad
4   Day-2           Bad
4   Day-3           Ok
5   Day-1           Ok
5   Day-2           Good
5   Day-3           Bad
```

(This is dummy sample. The actual survey has hundreds of Days, and many different types of answers.)

Is there any straight forward solution to this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pandas.melt` which transform data from wide to long format:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.melt(df, id_vars="User", var_name = "Question", value_name="Answer")

Out[246]:
  User  Question  Answer
0   1   Day-1   Good
1   2   Day-1   Good
2   3   Day-1   Good
3   4   Day-1   Bad
4   5   Day-1   Ok
5   1   Day-2   Good
6   2   Day-2   Ok
7   3   Day-2   Ok
8   4   Day-2   Bad
9   5   Day-2   Bad
10  1   Day-3   Bad
11  2   Day-3   Ok
12  3   Day-3   Ok
13  4   Day-3   Good
14  5   Day-3   Bad
```

---

Another option is to use `stack()`:

```
(df.set_index("User").stack()
   .rename_axis(("User", "Question"))
   .rename("Answer").reset_index())

Out[248]:
  User  Question Answer
0   1   Day-1   Good
1   1   Day-2   Good
2   1   Day-3   Bad
3   2   Day-1   Good
4   2   Day-2   Ok
5   2   Day-3   Ok
6   3   Day-1   Good
7   3   Day-2   Ok
8   3   Day-3   Ok
9   4   Day-1   Bad
10  4   Day-2   Bad
11  4   Day-3   Good
12  5   Day-1   Ok
13  5   Day-2   Bad
14  5   Day-3   Bad
```

Comment: Holy molly,  Pandas people have spent wayyyy to much time in the field. I DID NOT anticipate one line answer to this question!!!

Comment: @AjeetGanga Hmm. Being easy to use is definitely one of its advantages, but to master all the tricks to get where you want to still requires some time and practice nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

using `numpy`

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(
        User=df.User.values.repeat(len(df.columns) - 1),
        Question=np.tile(df.columns[1:], len(df.index)),
        Answer=df.values[:, 1:].ravel()
        ))[['User', 'Question', 'Answer']]

    User Question Answer
0      1    Day-1   Good
1      1    Day-2   Good
2      1    Day-3    Bad
3      2    Day-1   Good
4      2    Day-2     Ok
5      2    Day-3     Ok
6      3    Day-1   Good
7      3    Day-2     Ok
8      3    Day-3     Ok
9      4    Day-1    Bad
10     4    Day-2    Bad
11     4    Day-3   Good
12     5    Day-1     Ok
13     5    Day-2    Bad
14     5    Day-3    Bad
```

Comment: df.values[].ravel is the secret sauce !